# nullptr can't be detected by is.null in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I Used RCPP_MODULE to wrap following class.

```
struct Dummy
{
};
struct Test
{
    Dummy* get_dummy() { return nullptr; }
    Dummy* _dummy;
};
RCPP_MODULE(AF)
{
    class_<Dummy>("Dummy")
    .constructor();
    class_<Wrap>("Wrap")
    .constructor()
    .method("get_dummy", &Wrap::dummy);
}
```

when Wrap$get_dummy is called in R. is.null() returns false. did some check, it seems that R_NilValue should be used. but to use R_NilValue, return type of get_dummy() needs to be SEXP.

is it a must to change get_dummy() as below

```
SEXP get_dummy() { return R_NilValue; // or return Rcpp::Module_wrap<Dummy *>(_dummy) if a valid pointer is intended.
```

Comment: Correct as all interfaces to/from `.Call` must be `SEXP`.

Comment: but RCPP_MODULE converts c++ object to SEXP, this problem only exits for detecting nullptr. if get_dummy() returns a valid pointer. there is no need to change the signature of get_dummy().  Dummy * get_dummy() { return _dummy; } works perfectly.

Comment: You are assuming we have a `nullptr` to `R_NilValue` converter.

Comment: I thought there is one. so the answer is no. thanks for clearing this up.